# C++ template specialization for iterators

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, swap

I'd like to swap 2 values, pointed by iterators. So I want to specialize template function for taking iterators. Could you tell, please, how could I do this?

Function for non-iterators:

```
template <typename T>
void exch(T &a, T &b)
{
    T c( std::move(a) );
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(c);   
}
```

Function for iterators:

```
template <typename It>
void exch(It &a, It &b)
{
    auto c( std::move(*a) );
    *a = std::move(*b);
    *b = std::move(c);   
}
```

Of course, with 2 functions I get an error:

*/projects/DFSTL/main.cpp:17:6: error: redefinition of ‘template void exch(It&, It&)’*

Comment: SFINAE or tag dispatch on an `is_iterator` trait, whose implementation can easily be found on SO. But are you sure you really want to do this? What if someone really want to swap iterators?

Comment: You can use `std::iter_swap()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against doing this -- swapping `a` and `b`, and swapping the things indirectly referred to by `a` and `b`, is a tempting thing to overload.  But you end up getting really strange behavior if you do that.

If you must, the first step would involve writing your own `is_iterator` traits class.  This can be done through various methods.  One that works on some compilers is to use SFINAE resolution of `std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category`, and check if `input_iterator_tag` or `output_iterator_tag` is a base of that type.

You do usually need to detect `void*` and cv variants.  This is still implementation defined behavior, as `std::iterator_traits` on a non-iterator generates implementation defined results.

The more complex way is to examine each of the type axioms of iterators and test them, and if all pass say it is an iterator.

Once you have `is_iterator<T>`, you can use SFINAE:

```
template <class T, class=std::enable_if_t< !is_iterator<std::decay_t<T>>{} >>
void exch(T &a, T &b) {
  using std::swap;
  swap(a,b);
}
```

Function for iterators:

```
template <class It, class=std::enable_if_t< is_iterator<std::decay_t<It>>{} >>
void exch(It a, It b) {
  using std::iter_swap;
  iter_swap(a,b);
}
```

note that I called `swap` and `iter_swap` in an ADL-enabled context with `std::` lookup rather than manually implementing it.  This allows types that specialize their own `swap` in their enclosing namespace to automatically get their more optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

Both those template functions look identical to the compiler. That's why you get the compiler error.

Have you tried using this function: [`std::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)?

It looks like it does what you want - and has been specialized for all STL container types for which a swap makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, I know=) But I'm trying to write my own parallel STL implementation ^__^, in order to learn them and be a guru in templates=)